# Execute shell is not opening up file provided as string

Tags: excel, shell, vba

I am trying to solve an error in code written by someone else. The shell function running in an MS Excel VBA environment is as follows:

```
Public Function ExecCmd(cmdline$)
      Dim proc As PROCESS_INFORMATION
      Dim start As STARTUPINFO
      Dim ret&

      ' Initialize the STARTUPINFO structure:
      start.cb = Len(start)

      ' Start the shelled application:
      ret& = CreateProcessA(vbNullString, cmdline$, 0&, 0&, 1&, _
         NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0&, vbNullString, start, proc)

      ' Wait for the shelled application to finish:
         ret& = WaitForSingleObject(proc.hProcess, INFINITE)
         Call GetExitCodeProcess(proc.hProcess, ret&)
         Call CloseHandle(proc.hThread)
         Call CloseHandle(proc.hProcess)
         ExecCmd = ret&
   End Function
```

The `cmdline$` input is: "excel.exe W:\L\BDTP\Products\Mandate FS\OfferToolUpdate.xlsm"

When I run the code it opens another excel instance and attempts to open a file under "W:\L\BDTP\Products\Mandate.xlsx"... after two more error messages it tells me that it can also not find "FS\OfferToolUpdate.xlsm"

Clearly this error is produced some how due to the space in the naming convention of the Folder the file resides in.

**How can I open the file without changing the folder name?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you used example as shown at: `https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/129796` ...

Just update execution line to wrap out the file:

```
ExecCmd "excel.exe ""U:\ADMINISTRATION\Expenses\Some File.xlsx"""
```

Comment: I see you figured it out already... I had my response written 90% but got interrupted by coworker. Hope you find it helpful as well.

Comment: thank you. it is indeed helpful to me as I had no idea where the code came from. I'm not really versed in shell so this helps! +1 and Answer Check.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a viable workaround for the time being, though I'm sure there are more professional ways of going about it. I have changed the input command line to be in extra quotes:

```
"""" & "excel.exe W:\L\BDTP\Products\Mandate FS\OfferToolUpdate.xlsm" & """"
```